# How do I search for a subset in a last name field?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a set of students at a high school.  The counselors want to divide the students up by last name.  Here is the break down:

Counselor 1: A to F
Counselor 2: G to Hr
Counselor 3: Hs to O
Counselor 4: P - Z

The first one is easy, I just do a:

```
where last_name like '[A-F]%'
```

but the second counselor is giving me grief, because if I do:

```
where last_name like '[G-Hr]%'
```

...I get all students with last names of G, H, and R.  What is the best way to get what I want for counselor's 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counselor 2, try:

```
WHERE last_name LIKE 'G%' OR last_name LIKE 'H[a-r]%'
```

For counselor 3, try:

```
WHERE last_name LIKE 'H[s-z]%' OR last_name LIKE '[I-O]%'
```

Comment: It seems so simple when you put it like that ;)

Must have more coffee!

Comment: Now that you mention it, coffee does sound like a good idea.  The code should work in your case, but let's pretend for a minute that you had to split up students on the letter O, breaking at Oa-Om and On-Oz.  The code above would fail for students like O'Brien, O'Reilly, etc., and you'd probably either want to do a REPLACE to get rid of non-alpha characters, or add them to one of the LIKE statements.

Comment: Good point.  One other thing to note is that I put the condition in parenthesis because I do have some other where clauses, and without the parens, it was returning a lot more rows than I wanted.